# Missing Expression Error in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT DISTINCT manf FROM beers WHERE (SELECT price FROM sells WHERE price > 6);
```

The question is: Write a query with a sub-query to find manufacturers whos beers sell for more than $6 everywhere.
Total noob here.

Comment: how does beers and sells talk to one another? Is there a manf column in sells? You need a join telling sells what manufacturers?   

WHERE (SELECT price FROM sells WHERE price > 6 and manf.beers = manf.sells )

Comment: You say that the question is: *Write a query...*. That's not a question. Maybe your question could be, why is Oracle complaining with a *missing expression* error? Now that's a question.

Comment: Without knowing what your tables look like, it is extremely difficult to give an answer. Also your "question" does not formulate any question (ending with a question mark "?"). Please also elaborate on "everywhere". What do you mean by that? Please **edit** your question and improve it!

Answer (score -1):

You will need to join the tables. I assume that the `sells` table has a `beer_id` that you can use to link to the `beers` table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    beers.manf
FROM
    sells
    INNER JOIN beers
        ON sells.beer_name = beers.beer_name
WHERE
    sells.price > 6
ORDER BY beers.manf;
```

This returns all manufacturers having at least one costing more than $6.

---

If, however, all beers of a manufacturer must cost more than $6 then do this

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    beers.manf
FROM
    sells
    INNER JOIN beers
        ON sells.beer_name = beers.beer_name
WHERE
    sells.price > 6 AND
    beers.manf NOT IN (SELECT b.manf
                       FROM sells s INNER JOIN beers b ON s.beer_name = b.beer_name
                       WHERE s.price <= 6)
ORDER BY beers.manf;
```

---

However, without knowing the structure of your tables, it is difficult to give you a precise answer.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response. There is no beer ID. The beers table just contains name and manufacturer

Comment: The two tables `sells` and `beers` must have a column in common. Otherwise you cannot create a relation between them! Show us the columns of the two tables, please. Or is there a third table involved? We are tapping in the dark otherwise.

Comment: They have a beer name column in common

Comment: Well, then the solution seems obvious: replace `beer_id` by `beer_name` or whatever the column is named.

Comment: I admire your willingness to help out OP.  But I think OP would be better served by being encouraged to improve the question, rather than rushing to an answer for a question that, in its current form, and by your own admission, is lacking important information.